# How to manage windows wifi in ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, wifi

I have been looking for a library(or just sample code) to manage windows wifi. I have found a few for linux using commands, but windows doesn't offer a way like that.

Im looking a simple list networks, be able to tell whether open/wep/wpa, pass password as an argument, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke the [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785383(v=ws.10).aspx) tool you should probably be able to do most of what you want to do. For example, to dump all the visible networks, run:

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
# save this file as: "~/iwlist.rb"
# make executable: chmod +x ~/.iwlist.rb
# execute with: "~/iwlist.rb"

rpt= %x[iwlist wlan0 scan]
str=''
rpt.each_line{|line| str << (l.chomp + "\n") if /.*(Cell|Quality|Channel|ESSID| Authentication).*/ =~ l }
puts str
```

Comment: This doesn't work in windows, unless you know of somewhere I can get the iwlist binary for windows.